# How to select multiple value from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want display student result from database. But not work. I am unable to understand how to use code for this. Here some example.

My database like is - 'students_marks'.

---

```
id    StudentId    SubjectId      MarksWritten    MarksOral
1       A0001          1               30            10
2       A0001          2               30            10
3       A0001          3               30            10
4       A0002          1               30            10
5       A0002          2               30            10
6       A0002          3               30            10
7       A0003          1               30            10
8       A0003          2               30            10
9       A0003          3               30            10
```

I want output result like is as following.

```
StudentId - A0001
Subject   MarksWritten    MarkOral
Bengali        30             10
English        30             10
Mathematics    30             10
Total          90             30

StudentId - A0002
Subject   MarksWritten    MarkOral
Bengali        30             10
English        30             10
Mathematics    30             10
Total          90             30
```

My PHP code is -

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); $studentIds = str_replace(',', "','",$_GET["StudentID"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students_marks INNER JOIN std_subject ON std_subject.SubjectId=students_marks.SubjectId  WHERE StudentID IN ('" . implode("','", $studentIds) . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);  
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>


    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $row["StudentID"];?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksWritten"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksOral"];?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksWritten"]+$row["MarksOral"];?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<?php } ?>
```

std_subject

```
id     Subject     SubjectId
1      Bengali          1
2      English          2
3      Mathematics      3
```

When display result , the student id display for all subject nut i want just one time in table header.
Please help me, how to do this....
std_subject is subject details database table...

Comment: Please show us the complete PHP code you are using that produces the output that is not correct. You've only shown us a couple of small pieces of it.

Comment: i use this code only. i have no more code for this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The PHP you have starts a `while` statement but it's never finished and there is nothing being output.

Comment: I think you're looking for `GROUP BY` in your SQL query

Comment: So show us the COMPLETE `while` loop as that is definitely one area we need to know what you are doing

Comment: <?php error_reporting(0); $studentIds = str_replace(',', "','",$_GET["StudentID"]);
    $s = "SELECT * FROM students_marks INNER JOIN std_subject ON std_subject.SubjectId=students_marks.SubjectId WHERE StudentID IN ('" . implode("','", $studentIds) . "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $s);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <table>..</table>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51948603/edit) to add more information. Nobody can read code in comments

Comment: **ALSO** Where are you going to get the language names from like `Bengali` as they dont seem to exist in the table you show us

Comment: std_subject

    id     Subject     SubjectId

    1      Bengali          1

    2      English          2

    3      Mathematics      3

Comment: When Write full php code here not support

Comment: See my code again

Comment: Did you execute the query in mysql and see if it produces the required results?

Comment: hello sir ........

Answer (score 0):

You already have the array of student IDs in `$studentIds`

So iterate on each of the students' IDs and query the respective marks, for each student.

Try this PHP code:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); $studentIds = str_replace(',', "','",$_GET["StudentID"]); ?>
<?php foreach($studentIds as $studentID): ?>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $studentID;?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students_marks INNER JOIN std_subject ON std_subject.SubjectId=students_marks.SubjectId  WHERE StudentID = '".$studentID."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksWritten"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksOral"];?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["MarksWritten"]+$row["MarksOral"];?></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Here display only StudentId, Marks Not Display

Comment: I updated the query to have single quotes around the `$studentID` variable, it should work now.

Comment: Can I change while loop to foreach??

Comment: @sdgfdfsdfsdf Did you try the updated code? You can in theory change while loop to foreach but to me it seems the problem is in the query not being run properly.

Comment: When change WHERE StudentId=".$studentID to  StudentId = '".$studentID."' , its work one by one multiple not work

Comment: I try it without table - Here example  -
Its Work with - K20180000, K20180001 30 10 30 10 *
           I want - K20180000 30 10, K20180001 30 10
I change - StudentId IN ('".$studentID."')